# How can I make Notepad++ use ".txt" files as the default open file dialog filter?

Tags: notepad++

When I go to open files in NPP, the file types defaults to "all types (*.*)".

How can I make this default to ".txt"?

It may be a windows thing, since I'm sure it just uses the default windows file open dialog, but other programs (textpad, notepad) are able to default it.

Comment: It's certainly possible for a programmer to code, but there is no way to change the setting once its there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just finished reviewing the NPP source code, and have some additional details if you would like to seek a solution for yourself.  When you go File -> Open, the list of file extensions is loaded from the Scintilla (SciLexer.dll) file.

Now, when you go File -> Open, the `void Notepad_plus::fileOpen()` function is called (in the `NppIO.cpp` file).  Initially, the `All Types, *.*` filter is added to the filter list, and then, the `int Notepad_plus::setFileOpenSaveDlgFilters(FileDialog & fDlg, int langType)` function is called (in the same file).  This function goes through the Scintilla entries I mentioned above, and adds them to the passed `FileDialog`'s filter list.  The code in `FileOpen` looks like this:

```
fDlg.setExtFilter(TEXT("All types"), TEXT(".*"), NULL);
setFileOpenSaveDlgFilters(fDlg);
```

You can change the default filter index.  To do that, you can instead change those lines to this:

```
fDlg._ofn.nFilterIndex = 2L;
fDlg.setExtFilter(TEXT("All types"), TEXT(".*"), NULL);
setFileOpenSaveDlgFilters(fDlg);
```

That should set the filter index to the second one by default.

---

Another easy way to quick-fix this is to modify those lines (again, in `NppIO.cpp`) to look like this:

```
fDlg.setExtFilter(TEXT("Text files"), TEXT(".txt"),
                  TEXT("All types"),  TEXT(".*"), NULL);
setFileOpenSaveDlgFilters(fDlg);
```

That will ensure that Text files are the first filter on the list.  Do note that this will cause the .txt extension to be double-defined in the entries, but if you can live with that caveat, this should work fine.

Comment: well, it's for a programmer. do you have an way to change it directly on binaries (in a manual, editing with hex editor, or in a automatic way, applying a patch) or some modified release that has this modification?

Comment: I just tried to hex-edit the binary, but since the initial filter is only defined as `.*`, I can't insert any additional characters (I *can*, however, change the existing characters).  I'll look more into this, but as of now, I think it would be easier to re-compile it.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible for a programmer to code, but there is no way to change the setting once its there.Sorry.

Comment: NPP is open source. You could always make the change yourself and recompile!

Comment: at that point its a coding problem, and not for SU.

Comment: I could, it's probably a trivial fix (even if it would take a little bit to find it.) Of course, I wouldn't be guaranteed my plugins would still work the way I want them to, and would be a bit of a roundabout way to do something there's a chance is actually already exposed as a setting somehow.

Comment: Its not exposed (least as far as i can find). To find the place in the code, just find the text of the extensions, and set the default (should be in the same area).

Comment: I would argue that you *could* implement it as a feature (you just change the value of the filter index), but as it stands, it isn't one.  That being said, if you want to know how to change it, let me know and I will post it as an answer.  If you *did* make the change and recompile it yourself, your plugins would all still work just fine (and compiling NPP is easy since there's no additional dependencies, it's all C++ with STL).

Comment: You can also use the [Feature Request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612385) part of their SourceForge project page and request it yourself, or at least bring it to the developers attention.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars - it's unlikely to break any plugin.  All they are doing is calling the Common File Dialog in Win32. The txt extension is already there, so it's just a matter of setting the index number.

Answer (score 0):

By default you cannot change that "feature" in a normal way.

One solution is to change the program binaries, doing some code changes (if the code is open and you are licensed to do it) and recompile it to generate a different program binary or to "hack" the binary changing some files with an hex editor or a already created patch. Another solution is to change default Windows file dialogs in some way.

You can try that software, that should use the second solution: [File-Ex](http://www.file-ex.com/welcome.html)

With that, you can add some features to open and save dialogs and remember the chosen filter. Try that and post if it functioned for you.